# Setting Max length of string/.text

Tags: ios, xcode, string

I use buttons to display letters in a bar now this is the code I use

```
-(IBAction) clicked: (id)sender{
NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSString *newLabelText = titleOfButton;
labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", labelsText.text, newLabelText];

 //if ([newLabelText length] >= 5) newLabelText = [newLabelText substringToIndex:5];
 }
```

The problem I got is that I want it to be able to put in 5 letters max Is there anyone who can tell me how to do this?

thanks

Comment: First of all, you're leaking memory when calling `[[NSString alloc] init...]`without `release`ing it. Also, what exactly is the sense of `...initWithFormat:@"%@", string]`?

Comment: That's old code I just want to know how to get max length so it won't display a letter anymore when I already pressed 5.

Comment: Your alloc/init is perfectly fine, when using ARC. However the `initWithFormat:@"%@", titleOfButton` is useless, just use `titleOfButton` directly.

Comment: thank you I'm trying to get it out but Don't know the right way, it keeps giving me errors

Comment: Just use `NSString *newLabelText = titleOfButton;` or don't create a new variable at all.

Comment: oke cool thanks guys ill edit the main post can you have a look if it's alright now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line -

```
if ([newLabelText length] >= 5) newLabelText = [newLabelText substringToIndex:5];
```

...or apply the same to whatever string you want to truncate.

Check out the Apple Docs for some really useful NSString stuff

Comment: Oke thanks guys for the help, this is my new code -(IBAction) clicked: (id)sender{
    NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newLabelText = titleOfButton;
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", labelsText.text, newLabelText];
    
     if ([labelsText.text length] >= 5) labelsText.text = [labelsText.text substringToIndex:5];
}

Comment: changed your line to: for anyone else that might want this :) if ([labelsText.text length] >= 5) labelsText.text = [labelsText.text substringToIndex:5];

Comment: labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", labelsText.text, titleOfButton]; left the second NSString out